# How to buy an iPhone 6s and use it in China?

Tags: hardware-recommendation, iphone

I'd like to buy a new model iPhone 6s 16 GB ("Rose Gold" color) and use it in China.

- when purchasing it in Apple Store, what options should I choose so the phone will bear no service contract which is useless for me?
- How to make sure it is "unlocked" so it can be used with a local service company in China?  What sort of SIM card does this iPhone require for it to be compatible?
- Could the interface language be set to Chinese language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to buy a new model iPhone 6s 16 GB ("Rose Gold" color) and use it in China.

First off, the iPhone 6S is a great choice. It's the gold-standard of all phones, but whatever you do, DON'T buy the 16 GB model. This isn't an iPhone 3GS or a cheap Android phone, it's a brand new iPhone 6S and it shoots 4K videos. Formatted, with iOS on it, you should have less than 12 GB to work with. Put 2 HD movies on it, and your just about out of storage. Get *at least* the 64 GB model, it's way worth the $100, IMO, plus when you go to sell it for an upgrade in a few years, you'll get back most of that $100, anyway. Me? I've already bought a 128 GB iPhone 6S on Verizon.

> When purchasing it in Apple Store, what options should I choose so the phone will bear no service contract which is useless for me?

Not a lot, other than get the iPhone on T-Mobile, which should be available to buy outright ($750 for 64 GB model) and will come SIM-free and without a contact, just make sure that it will work on whatever carrier you wish to put it on in China.

> How to make sure it is "unlocked" so it can be used with a local service company in China? What sort of SIM card does this iPhone require for it to be compatible?

Apple doesn't sell unlocked iPhone 6Ss, yet. I asked an Apple rep about this and they said maybe in a few months, but there is the very small chance that your carrier doesn't require the iPhone to be unlocked, like Straight Talk, but probably not in China.

> Could the interface language be set to Chinese language?

Yes. China and the US are Apple's biggest customers.